# ComboBox still diplaying item in disable mode

Tags: c#, combobox

This is the situation. 
I have an Inventory Update Function :

```
    public void UpdateInventoryList()
            {
                dgInventory.RowHeadersVisible = false;

                dgInventory.ColumnCount = 2;
                dgInventory.Columns[0].Name = "Name";
                dgInventory.Columns[0].Width = 112;
                dgInventory.Columns[1].Name = "Quantity";

                dgInventory.Rows.Clear();


                foreach (InventoryItem inventoryItem in _player.Inventory)
                {
                    if (invetoryItem.Quantity > 0)
                    {
                        dgInventory.Rows.Add(new[] { inventoryItem.Details.Name, inventoryItem.Quantity.ToString() });

                    }


                }

            }
```

Then i have a ComboBox for the Player Pets :

```
private void UpdatePet()
        {
            List<Pet> pets = new List<Pet>();

            foreach (InventoryItem inventoryItem in _player.Inventory)
            {
                if (inventoryItem.Details is Pet)
                {
                    if (inventoryItem.Quantity > 0)
                    {
                        pets.Add((Pet)inventoryItem.Details);
                    }
                }
            }

            if (pets.Count == 0)
            {

                cboPet.Enabled = false;
                btAttack.Enabled = false;

            }
            else
            {
                cboPet.DataSource = pets;
                cboPet.DisplayMember = "Name";
                cboPet.ValueMember = "ID";

                cboPet.SelectedIndex = 0;
            }

            cboPet.SelectedIndexChanged += new System.EventHandler(cboPet_SelectedIndexChanged);
        }
```

Ok now i have a function that if you push the button "SACRIFICE" it deletes the Pets from Inventory and then in the ComboBox too :

```
 private void btSacrifice_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Pet currentpet = (Pet)cboPet.SelectedItem;


        if (currentpet.Sacrificable == true && _player.CurrentHP < _player.MaxHP)
        {
            foreach (InventoryItem oi in _player.Inventory)
            {
                if (oi.Details.ID == currentpet.ID)
                {
                    oi.Quantity--;

                }
                UpdateInventoryList();
            }
            if (_player.CurrentHP + currentpet.HealHP >= _player.MaxHP)
            {
                _player.CurrentHP = _player.MaxHP;
                barHP.Value = _player.CurrentHP;
                lblHp.Text = _player.CurrentHP.ToString();

                btSacrifice.Enabled = false;
                btCallPet.Enabled = false;

            }
            else
            _player.CurrentHP = (_player.CurrentHP + currentpet.currentHP);
            barHP.Value = _player.CurrentHP;
            lblHp.Text = _player.CurrentHP.ToString();

            btSacrifice.Enabled = false;
            btCallPet.Enabled = false;
        }
        else if (!currentpet.Sacrificable == true)
        {
            tboxCombat.Text += "Not Sacrificable Pet!" + Environment.NewLine;
        }



        UpdateInventoryListI();
        UpdatePet();

    }
```

It all works perfect but if i have just one pet in my inventory and sure in my combobox when it deletes the pet the combobx is disabled and it shows the name of the pet, in this case the pet i have deleted. if i have more then one pet then the combobox is enable (and this is ok) and displaying the other pet i have.

Why if i have just one pet ("item" in the combobox) when deleting still diplaying the name of it?

Hope you can help and thanks!

Eugene

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should remove the selection of `ComboBox` as well:

```
if (pets.Count == 0)
{
   cboPet.SelectedIndex = -1;  //remove selection             
   cboPet.Enabled = false;
   btAttack.Enabled = false;               

}
```

Comment: Thank this just line solve the problem. (Without addind DataSource = null)

Comment: @EugenioOlivieri, this can only solve/hide your current problem, but your code has other problems to worry about.

Comment: Why? Wheres the problems?

Comment: @EugenioOlivieri, check them in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

It is because when there is no item your code will only disable the `combobox` without resetting it's `DataSource`: So you need to add `cboPet.DataSource = null;` like below:

```
if (pets.Count == 0)
{
   cboPet.DataSource = null;  //add this              
   cboPet.Enabled = false;
   btAttack.Enabled = false;               

}
else
{
   cboPet.DataSource = pets;
   cboPet.DisplayMember = "Name";
   cboPet.ValueMember = "ID";
   cboPet.SelectedIndex = 0;
}
```

Also, a side-notes: you should probably define `List<Pet> pets` in the class level, so that you don't need to keep setting the `DataSource`.

And a second note: you are subscribing multiple times  `cboPet.SelectedIndexChanged += new System.EventHandler(cboPet_SelectedIndexChanged);`, move it out of the current function, or unsubscribe before registering again.

Comment: So i have to add in if(pets.Count == 0){cboPet.Enabled = false; btAttack.Enabled = false; cboPet.Datasource = null ?

Comment: Addng datasource = null, gives me an error 'System.NullReferenceException' in Magicians_game.exe not handled in the utent code.

Info: Referring to an object do not realated to an object instance.

Comment: @EugenioOlivieri, the exception is not directly related to the line you just added. can you tell which line gives you this exception? I guess it's in your `cboPet_SelectedIndexChanged`?